# Online Audio/Video editor, or lightweight Mac equivalent?

Tags: osx

I have a short MP4 video (with sound), and a separate short MP3 file. I am looking for a way to replace the audio of the first file with the audio of the second one.

Is there an online service that I might use for that task, and if not, what is the most lightweight app solution for doing it on a Mac?

*Cross-posted [at Ask Different.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269788/online-audio-video-editor-or-lightweight-mac-equivalent)*

Comment: I am adding this as a comment as I am not entirely sure if it is feasible, but look at FFMPeg CLI :) Should be possible

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing `ffmpeg` and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/how-to-add-a-new-audio-not-mixing-into-a-video-using-ffmpeg) to map the video and audio files.